# zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/zookeeper-server-start

Tags: homebrew, apache-zookeeper

I was installed kafka using brew (`brew install kafka`). After that I tried to start the zookeeper in my machine, I got the error `zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/zookeeper-server-start` in mac apple silicon chip or mac m1 lap.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the script path in my local.

from: `/usr/local/bin/zookeeper-server-start`

to: `/opt/homebrew/bin/zookeeper-server-start`

then It's working.

Comment: You should really be using `brew services start zookeeper`... Also, as of latest Kafka, Zookeeper isn't required

Answer (score -2):

To Run The Zookeeper Server on a Mac :
Open Terminal and use cd to navigate the Kafka folder and run the below command.

**bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties**